# What am I doing wrong with std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr in my linked list implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I've never used smart pointers before, so I decided to try out implementing a basic little linked list, just to see how it works. The program bellow outputs only the first element of the list, i.e. `5`, and then just exits.

In the `print()` function, the `while` loop iterates only once, which means that the list contains only one element even though it should contain 3.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class list {
private:
    struct node {
        int val;
        std::shared_ptr<node> next;
        node(int _val) : val(_val), next(nullptr) {}
    };
    std::shared_ptr<node> head;

public:
    list() {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    void push_back(int val) {
        std::unique_ptr<node> new_node(new node(val));
        if(head == nullptr) {
            head = std::move(new_node);
        } else {
            std::shared_ptr<node> curr(head);
            while(curr != nullptr) {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            curr = std::move(new_node);
        }
    }

    void print() {
        std::shared_ptr<node> curr(head);
        while(curr != nullptr) {
            std::cout << curr->val << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<list> lst(new list());

    lst->push_back(5);
    lst->push_back(10);
    lst->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not appending the node to the end correctly. This part of your code:

```
while(curr != nullptr) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr = std::move(new_node);
```

should instead be:

```
while(curr->next != nullptr) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr->next = std::move(new_node);
```